# The criterion for conic sheaves

Tags: sheaf-theory

In Kashiwara and Schapira's book , chapter 3.7
It says if $X$ is a locally compact space, $F\in Ob(\mathbf{D}^+(\mathfrak{Mod}(A_X)))$, $\mu$ an action of $\mathbb{R}^+$ on $X$,  consider the map $\mu,p$ from $X\times \mathbb{R}^+$ to $X$ where $p$ is the projection, $p(x,a)=x$.
Then $F$ is a conic sheaf is equivalent to $p^{-1}F\simeq \mu^{-1}F$ which is equivalent to $p^!F\simeq \mu^!F$, here $^!$ denote the dual functor of $Rf_!$.
How can we prove that these two propositions are equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X,Y$ are orientable and $f : X \to Y$ is a submersion then $f^! = f^*[d]$, proving the claim.

More generally, a submersion of manifold $f : X \to Y$ gives an isomorphism $f^! \cong f^* \otimes \omega_{X/Y}$ where $\omega_{X/Y} = f^* \underline{\Bbb{R}}_Y$ is the relative dualizing sheaf. This is a rank $1$ sheaf concentrated in degree $d$, so this is an invertible sheaf and the equivalence follows.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your argument. It looks like you're saying implicitely that $\mu^{!}\mathbb{R}_Y\cong p^{!}\mathbb{R}_Y$, but I'm not sure why this should be true.

Comment: And also, is $\mu$ a topological submersion?

Comment: @mfox : Hi, thanks for your comment and sorry for the delay. Indeed there are some flaws in the argument. First, one can't apply the second paragraph because one should check as you said that $f^* \Bbb R_Y \cong \mu^* \Bbb R_Y$. I think $\mu$ should be a submersion, because the fiber of $\mu$ in each case is isomorphic to $\Bbb R_+$. Anyway in this special case I strongly suspect that $f^*[d] = f^!$ and $\mu^*[d] = \mu^!$ so the argument would still works, but I don't see how to prove it now. If I have more time this week I'll try to fix it, I'm really sorry for that.

Comment: You can write $\mu = pf$, where $f : X\times\mathbb{R}^{+}\rightarrow X\times\mathbb{R}^{+}$ is a homeomorphism defined by $(x, t)\rightarrow(\mu(x, t), t)$, so $\mu$ is a topological submersion. Does this imply $\mu^{!}\mathbb{R}_Y\cong p^{!}\mathbb{R}_Y$?